# Iteration breaking before I want it to

Tags: php, html, iteration

I am trying to get a program to reiterate until both the $heads variable and $tails variable is greater than 0.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  The while loop always gets broken after just one iteration.

```
<?php
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr><td>Person</td><td>Heads</td><td>Tails</td><td>Total</td></tr>";



for ($person=1; $person < 11; $person++){
echo "<tr><td>Person $person </td>";
$both = 0;
$heads = 0;
$tails = 0;
$total = 0;
while ($both < 1){
    do {
        $total++;
        $random = rand(1,2);
        if ($random == 1){
            $heads++;
        } else{
            $tails++;
        }  
    } while (($tails < 0)  && ($heads < 0));
    $both = 1;

}
echo "<td>$heads</td><td>$tails</td><td>$total</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
} while (($tails < 0)  && ($heads < 0));
```

it appears that neither `$tails` nor `$heads` will ever be strictly less than `0`, so that will always be false. Try `<= 0` for both.

Also, logically, you want to loop again if *either* of those conditions is true, right? So use `||` instead of `&&`.

Result:

```
} while (($tails <= 0) || ($heads <= 0));
```

---

Also, I'm a little curious about the `while ($both < 1)` loop. It appears that you assign `$both = 0` before the loop, and you assign `$both = 1` at the end of its iteration. That would guarantee the loop is only executed once, in which case -- what's the point of having that loop? Perhaps that's just unfinished code at this point?

Comment: Worked beautifully.  Thank you so much.  I'm not sure why I thought it was the && operator!

Comment: For your question, it only assigns $both = 1 after both $tails and $heads are greater than 0.

Comment: @stytown Right, but you won't exit that inner loop until both `$tails` and `$heads` are greater than `0` anyway, so you'd never run the outer loop more than once.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I took out that while loop, and it still worked as planned.  I guess I just didn't see it the way you did.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to keep flipping coins until you get at least one head *and* at least one tail result? And at the same time keep track of how many times you flipped?

I would have coded like this:

```
$heads = 0;
$tails = 0;
$total = 0;

while( true ) {
    $total ++;
    $random = rand( 0, 1 ); // 0 for tail, 1 for head
    if( $random ) $heads ++;
    else          $tails ++;

    if( $heads >= 1 && $tails >= 1 ) break;
}
```

The while loop will continue to run infinitely until both $heads and $tails become one or greater.

Comment: In my opinion this code is more readable and cleaner, but Wiseguy did fix the problem in your code.

Comment: wont $random always evaluate true in the if statement?

Comment: In this one, how will it know which variable ($heads or $tails) to add to?

Comment: @AnPel Oh oops, I thought it returns 0 or 1. Not 1 or 2. I guess I need rand( 0, 1 ), not rand( 1, 2 ). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @stytown Every iteration of the while loop, the if statement checks if both $heads and $tails are greater than 0. If they both are, then exit the while loop (and you can tell how many times the while loop iterated by printing out $total).

Comment: @hobbes3 yes I see that now.  Thank you for the explanation.